# The column sort in my tablesorter is overriding the checkall check box in my table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, tablesorter

I'm using the jQuery-2.1.3 version, and applied the jQuery tablesorter to a table to each column heading. My table also has checkboxes, and I need to be able to checkall the checkboxes in the first column. The function I'm using does correctly checkall, but also sorts the table. I am also not able to uncheckall, instead the column just toggles between ascending/descending order.

Here is a link to view my example: http://bitalicious.co/robyn/

```
<fieldset>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <!-- checkall is not currentlly working -->
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkall">Business Name
          </label>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>Contact Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th class="{sorter: false}"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">ABC Corporation
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Brandon</td>
      <td>290 Plano Pkwy</td>
      <td>Plano</td>
      <td>TX</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Modify <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Duplicate</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">Jungle Crabs
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Robyn</td>
      <td>511 Fort Worth Dr</td>
      <td>Denton</td>
      <td>TX</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Modify <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Duplicate</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">Big Plates Restaurants
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Justin</td>
      <td>1329 Centrury Blvd</td>
      <td>Irving</td>
      <td>TX</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Modify <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Duplicate</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Here's the JavaScript I was using**

```
<!-- jQuery Tablesorter -->
<script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script type="">
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
        } 
    );
</script>

<!-- Check all column header currently conflicting with the column sort -->
<!-- refer to site http://briancray.com/posts/check-all-jquery-javascript --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.checkall').on('click', function () {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I already have a demo that does this - http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/165/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all that is missing is to stop propagation of the click:

```
$('.checkall').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the checkbox is part of the column header, so anytime the header is clicked, the checkbox's click handler runs. The first solution off the top of my head is pull the checkboxes into their own column. This makes the checkboxes their own sortable column, which is unfortunate, but there's a configuration option in `.tablesorter` that allows you to ignore the checkbox field:

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({
    headers: {
      0: { sorter: false, parser: false }
    }
});
```

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/8pus6k36/1) for a full example. The basic gist is:

```
<fieldset>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkall"/>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>Business Name</th>
      <th>Contact Name</th>
  ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>ABC Corporation</td>
      <td>Brandon</td>

  ...
```

Comment: Thanks the quick answer. I was about to go with your solution, but will be using the answer from @Mottie

Comment: Simple is always better.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, albeit un-semantically is to position the main checkbox outside the table, then reposition over the table head.

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-boss">
    <label>
        <!-- checkall is not currentlly working -->
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkall"> Business Name
    </label>
</div>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>

            </th> 
            <th>Contact Name</th> 
            <th>Address</th> 
            <th>City</th> 
            <th>State</th>
            <th class="{sorter: false}"></th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
```

Then the CSS

```
.checkbox-boss {
    position: relative;
    top: 42px;
    left: 12px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```